# Overwriting an index in struct in C from a file

Tags: c, string, struct, linked-list, overwrite

I've implemented code that; If a car in the queue wants to change which type of wash is selected, then this must be able to change for that car:
The program reads from a file, where it's called CarsQ.txt; containing
Now the question is, why is it not overwriting the wash type, it just prints the queue out.

```
AV96888 VW alm
KD65656 Audi luksus
AX21878 Ford alm
CN32323 VW alm
NB21214 Ford luksus
UM21878 Ford alm
AV54361 Tesla luksus
```

^ different file, it has two wash types, alm and luksus (ordinary and luxury)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#define N 100 
     
typedef struct Car
{
    char Numberplate[N];
    char Brand[N];
    char Wash[N];
    struct car *next;
    struct car *prev; 
} Car;
    
typedef struct  queue
{
    struct Car *a[N];
    int Total;
    Car *front;
    Car *rear;
} queue;

void New_Wash_Type(struct queue *k,const char *Tree)
{
    struct Car *p;
    
    p=malloc(sizeof(struct Car));
    
    strcpy(p->Wash,Tree);
    
    
    p = k->a[1];
}

int main ()
{
    printf("\nPrint queue:");
    struct Car *p;
    struct queue k;
    char One[N], Two[N], Tree[N];
    
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("CarsQ.txt", "r");
    
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s",One,Two,Tree)==3)
    {
        p=malloc(sizeof(struct Car));
        strcpy(p->Numberplate,One);
        strcpy(p->Brand,Two);
        strcpy(p->Wash,Tree);
    
        printf("\n%s %s %s",p->Numberplate,p->Brand,p->Wash);
    
        k.a[k.Total++] =p;
    
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    printf("\n\nOpgave 12:");
    New_Wash_Type(&k,"luxury");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `k.Total = 0;`

Comment: `New_Wash_Type` doesn't overwrite anything. It creates a new `Car`, puts the new wash into it, but doesn't update the queue with that.

Comment: `New_Wash_Type` should overwrite `k->a[1]->Wash`, it doesn't need to allocate a new Car

Comment: it's just a small part of a larger code, where k.total=0, is initialized, thanks.